# Distinguish between "unanswered" and "unsolved"

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Personally, I think we need to distinguish between unanswered questions and unsolved questions.  Questions with answers are not unanswered, but could be unsolved if the answers are poor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree there is a semantic difference, and there is a corresponding display difference (0 answers and red box vs N answers and green box). However, from a use case perspective, I believe grouping them together under the same tag is preferable. If the user wants to personally be more selective, the visual indicators are there to allow for that.

Comment: It's not about semantics, if I receive totally useless answers I would like to tag the question like unanswered or unsolved and have the question on top, like the new and unanswered questions so others can help solve the problem

Comment: It makes no sense to re-post the question losing the history of the bad answers.

Comment: I like the idea of "My question is still active because I haven't received a suitable answer" tag.

Comment: It makes sense to re-post a question in a different manner to get a suitable answer without losing all your reputation doing it.  Sometimes, good meanings are lost to bad interpretations.